# How to retrieve data from MySQL array and make checkbox checked in list

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form in which I display numbers of company with checkbox. User checked these company and save this in a database table. Now I want to make an update form where I want that when data retrieve from database the checkbox is already checked in list which is checked by user while entering data.

Basically i want that when user fetches his stored results from database, he should be able to see which checkbox's he ticked earlier.

Screenshot of values which is saved by user

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

List of that values which is save in `select_fi` columns

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have no idea how i can do it i just want a way of how i can do it?

Comment: At least you could show your database structure. What have you tried to approach the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i update my question

Comment: Mate, still no structure is there. You have shown the contents.

Comment: It would be better practice to create another table and store the list in this table than to store the selection as a comma-separated list. Please read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) for more information on how and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch the current user's `select_fi` previously checked boxes (e.g. `1,2,3` ) you can convert it to `PHP array` with `$current_user_checked_boxes_ids = explode(",",$string)`.

And then, inside the `PHP` loop you have to print the checkboxes in `HTML`you can write something like:

```
if (in_array(
$current_check_box_id, 
$current_user_checkboxes_ids))
echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
else
echo '<input type="checkbox">';
```

Comment: which part can't you do?

Comment: As you tell in your answer i already do it but problem is that i want checked only that checkbox which is save in database and other checkbox will be unchecked

Comment: when your printing the HTML for the checkboxes do something like `if (in_array($current_check_box_name, $check_boxes_fetched_from_database)) echo "checked='checked'";`

Comment: or just edit your question with the code you're trying...

Comment: I've edited my answer..

Comment: have you tried this? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like :

```
<?php
 $sql=select * from table;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 if($row['column1']!=''){
 ?>
  use the html code to mark the  checkbox
 <?php
}else{
 ?>
 use the html code to show checkbox without mark
<?php
}
?>
```